# Give a dropdown select a title that still shows in corner after a selection has been made

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to create a select dropdown where the "default" is shown in the top left hand corner of the dropdown menu even after a selection is made. I have started with something like this:

```
<select>
 <option selected hidden>Currency</option>
 <option value="USD">USD</option>
 <option value="MEX">MEX</option>            
</select>
```

But I want to do something like this:

[image]

Is there a way to position a span text right above the currently selected option like in the picture above?

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't exactly the most elegant solution, you could do something cheesy and manually position a span over the dropdown like so:

```css
select {
    padding: 23px 0px 7px 6px;
    width: 110px;
    font-family: 'Arial';
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
}

span.cover {
    display: block;
    margin-top: -40px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-family: 'Arial';
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #199ddb;
}

body {
    background-color: #199ddb;
}
```

```html
<select>
    <option>USD</option>
    <option>MEX</option>
</select>
<span class="cover">Currency</span>

<select>
    <option>Mr.</option>
    <option>Mrs.</option>
    <option>Ms.</option>
</select>
<span class="cover">Title</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#custom-container {
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-size: 14px;
}

select {
  padding: 25px 30px 5px 5px;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 5px;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="custom-container">
  <span>Currency</span>
  <select>
    <option>USD</option>
    <option>MEX</option>
  </select>
</div>
```